# Docker application cant connect to database after update

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony

on my company I have an old Symfony application running in a Docker-Container. This application is connected to a SQL-database, which is also running inside a Docker-Container.

The image was built with php:7.2-apache-stretch which isn't available anymore. Symfony was version 3.2

I was trying to update the image, but now the application cant connect to the database anymore.
When Im trying to get the repository, I get the error:
`An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`
on file `/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php`

This is part of the old Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache-stretch
.
.
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/test\
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpng-dev libjpeg-dev unzip\
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql shmop zip gd \
    && a2enmod rewrite ssl socache_shmcb \
    && service apache2 restart \
        && composer install \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/test\
    && useradd -rm -d /home/test-s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 503 test\
```

and this is my new Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer
FROM php:7.4.20-apache


COPY --chown=33:33 . /srv/test
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/lib/
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/lib/php
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

WORKDIR /srv/test

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/test

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
                zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && useradd -rm -d /home/test-s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 503 test\
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && apt install nano \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN composer install
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: test-docker
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/test
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: 'serverName=localhost'
      XDEBUG_SESSION: 'PHPSTORM'
      XDEBUG_MODE: 'debug'
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    container_name: test_mysql
    volumes:
      - .docker/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "testapp",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ,"lib/googleWallet"]

    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.33",
        "symfony/symfony": "v3.4.49",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1.0",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^1.4",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "1.4",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3",
        "iio/libmergepdf": "~3.0",
        "justinrainbow/json-schema": "^5.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0",
        "pkpass/pkpass": "^1.2",
        "endroid/qr-code": "^2.5",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.149",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0",
        "behat/behat": "~3.1@dev",
        "behat/mink-extension": "~2.2.0",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.2.0",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7",
        "nelmio/alice": "2.*",
        "leaphub/phpcs-symfony2-standard": "~2.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4.19"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you by chance also update your mysql image? It appears you are running mysql 8 which is fundamentally different to previous versions in a way that it uses a different method of authentication. You may change the authentication plugin back using "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password" specified as command for your mysql container.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the old image was mariadb:10.4.4. Also built the image with the old version, but the error is still there

Comment: Judging by your other question your database configuration appears to point to 127.0.0.1. it should however point to `mysql`as that is the hostname of the database container.

Comment: I t ried every combination. Another name, another port. Doctrine cant connect to the container, but I can connect via DataGrip